# Is it threadsafe to move a file while writing to it?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, nio

I have a `BufferedWriter` which writes some data to a file. On a different thread the file may be renamed by using *nio* `Files.move` method:

```
    Path path = Paths.get( "name" );
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( path.toFile() ) );
    writer.write( "some data\n" );
    new Thread( () -> {

      // do something

      Files.move( path, path.resolveSibling( "newName" ) );
    } ).start();

    // do something

    writer.write( "more data\n" );
    writer.close();
```

I have tested a bit and it always worked fine but I might be just lucky, so my question is: 
is it thread safe to call `move` method while another thread may write to the file? If not, do I have to synchronize move and write operations or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: It's not filesystem safe (thread safety is concerned with memory issues). Why do you have a thread that moves files while other threads may be writing into them?

Comment: Whether or not it's safe, it sounds decidedly ill-advised.

Comment: On Unix/Linux file systems it should be safe. Inodes identify a file, and function somewhat like a directory entry.

Comment: @Kayaman I am receiving data from a network which I want to store to a file. The actual file name is parsed by another thread so as soon as it is available I want to change it from temporary to the actual name.

Comment: @MaxZofal that sounds awkward. Is getting the filename so complicated that it requires a separate thread? Wouldn't it make more sense to rename the file when it's finished downloading, which can be done by the thread that downloads it? With the added benefit of knowing that the file is downloaded fully.

Comment: ok probably it is awkward... but the downloading may last long and the parsing is done by a separate thread anyway so I thought it could be done like that

Comment: In most file-systems, a file is an "object" that is referenced by its directory entry or entries.  *(A Unix/Linux "hard link" is when more than one directory entry refers to the same file, known in that parlance as an `inode`.)*  However ... as Andy well observes, "you really don't want to be doing things like that!"

Comment: @MikeRobinson, a unix hard link is a name for a file. A newly created file in a unix file system has one hard link to begin with. You can use the `ln` command to create additional hard links to an existing file. The `rm` command destroys hard links. There is no command or system call to delete a file. The OS automatically deletes a file when two conditions are met: (a) its last hard link has been destroyed, and (b) no process still has the file open.